# java Constructores y métodos .Nivel Inicial

Tags: java, array, poo, constructor

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Cargar por teclado un arreglo de *n* componentes y multiplicarlo por el valor *k* que también se ingresa por teclado.

Como estoy empezando en la (POO) el ejercicio esta resuelto dentro de una sola clase que contiene  el metodo main y sus demas  funciones. El libro propone ahora crear una clase llamada arreglo para no sobrecargar el metodo main, la clase arreglo contiene metodos que estan marcados a continuacion, el problema es que no sé para que son necesarios.

```
public class arreglo
{ private int v []; 
    public arreglo()
    { v =  new  int [5]; 
    }

    public arreglo(int n)
    { if (n<= 0 )n = 5 ;
        v = new int [n];
    }

    public int length() //Con que fin se crea este Metodo ?
    {return v.length   ;  // en que afecta que no este?
    }

    public int getComponent(int i ) //Con que fin se crea este Metodo?
    { return  v[i]; 
    }

    public void setComponent(int x, int i)//Con que fin se crea este Metodo?
    {
        v[i] = x;
    }

    public void multiplicar(int k)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            v[i] = v[i] * k;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String r = "{ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            r = r + v[i];
            if (i != v.length - 1) { r = r + ", "; }
        }
        r = r + " }";
        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo la clase con las respuestas a tus preguntas.

```
public class Arreglo 
{
    private int[] v;

    public Arreglo(int n)
    { if (n<= 0 )n = 5 ;
        v = new int [n];
    }


    public int length() //Con que fin se crea este Metodo ? R=TE DEVUELVE EL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO
    {
        return v.length   ;  // en que afecta que no este? R=NO TE DEVOLVERIA EL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO
    }

    public int getComponent(int i ) //Con que fin se crea este Metodo? R=TE DEVUELVE EL ELEMENTO DEL ARREGLO EN LA POSICION i
    { 
        return  v[i]; 
    }

    public void setComponent(int x, int i)//Con que fin se crea este Metodo? //R= PARA CAMBIAR EL VALOR DEL ARREGLO EN LA PSICION I DANDOLE EL VALOR X
    {
        v[i] = x;
    }

    public void multiplicar(int k)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            v[i] = v[i] * k;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String r = "{ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            r = r + v[i];
            if (i != v.length - 1) { r = r + ", "; }
        }
        r = r + " }";
        return r;
    }

}
```

En el main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el tamaño del arreglo:");
        int tamArreglo=leer.nextInt(); //Le pides al usuario el tamaño del arreglo

        Arreglo arreglo=new Arreglo(tamArreglo); //CREAS LA INSTANCIA, EN ESTE CASO ESTAS CREANDO UN ARREGLO DE n elementos ELEMENTOS

        for (int i = 0; i < tamArreglo; i++) //AQUI INSERTAMOS VALORES AL ARREGLO
        {
            System.out.println("Introduce el valor:");
            int valor=leer.nextInt();
            arreglo.setComponent(valor, i);
        }

        System.out.println(arreglo.toString()); //PUEDES IMPRIMIR EL ARREGLO ORIGINAL

        System.out.println("Introduce el multiplicador:");
        int multiplicador=leer.nextInt();
        arreglo.multiplicar(multiplicador); //AQUI MULTIPLICAS TODOS LO VALORES DEL ARREGLO POR EL MULTIPLICADOR

        System.out.println(arreglo.toString()); //IMPRIMES EL ARREGLO YA MULTIPLICADO
    }
}
```

Obtienes algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el main tambien deje comentarios para que entiendas que hace cada cosa. Espero te ayude. Un saludo.

Comment: Alexyz flores , gracias a tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda. entonces se puede decir que siempre que cree un objeto de tipo arreglo o para instanciar un objeto de tipo arreglo , la clase en la que se encuentra tengo que definir los métodos que me remarcaste. como por ejemplo get length , get component. desde ya muchísimas gracias , saludos